# Parsing JSON via javascript getting error: json.parse:unexpected character

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova-plugins

I am trying to parse an API data that i receive via ajax. I have no control over the api json structure. When i try to parse it using this code i get this error:

```
json.parse:unexpected character
```

and no data output on divs.I spend past 2 days couldn't fix it. Could you guys tell me how to fix it.Thanks

data.html content:

```
"[\r\n  {\r\n    \"itemID\": \"1\",\r\n    \"itemTitle\": \"First\",\r\n    \"itemText\": \"first one\",\r\n    \"ThumbUrl\": \"http://somesite.com/1.jpg\",\r\n    \"itemContent\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"itemID\": \"2\",\r\n    \"itemTitle\": \"Second\",\r\n    \"itemText\": \"  second one\",\r\n    \"ThumbUrl\": \"http://somesite/2.jpg\",\r\n    \"itemContent\": null\r\n  }\r\n]"
```

javascript:

```
  <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function ajax() {

$.get("./data.html", function(data){   

data = data.replace("\"[", "["); 
data = data.replace("]\"", "]"); 
$("#area1").text(data);

// parse JSON response
var json = $.parseJSON(data);

console.log(json);

    // then loop the single items
    for(i in json)
    {
       // create HTML code
       var div = "<div class=\"image\">\n" + 
       "<a href=\"javascript:dofunction('./test.php?title=" + json[i].itemTitle + "&TargetUrl=http://somesite.com/" + json[i].itemID + "')\">\n" +
       "<img src=\""+ json[i].ThumbUrl +"\" alt=\"..\" />\n" +
       "</a>\n" +
       "</div>\n";

      $("#myDiv").append(div);
    }
});

}
</script>

<body>
<button onclick="ajax()">test</button>
<br>orginal data:<br>
<textarea id="area1" rows="4" cols="50" ></textarea>
<div id='myDiv'></div>
</html>
```

console.log(json):

```
JSON.parse: unexpected character
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
Line 4
```

Comment: Your json should be invalid. Validate it here jsonlint.com

Comment: Can you post what the `console.log(json);` spits out? But yeah @Santosh has the right idea -- check what is invalid with your json.

Comment: Bad formatted JSON.

Comment: try setting dataType argument to `"text"` then see what output is after your `replace()`

Comment: The json is valid..i think that those `data.replace` are the cause of those issues.....

Comment: @Hackerman not valid with those external quotes if they actually exist

Comment: Thanks for replies. I validated it and it says Valid JSON. This is the content of console.log(json) :JSON.parse: unexpected character
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
Line 4

Comment: output before you try parse...then run that through validator

Comment: Yeah...I validated the Json too on jsonlint....

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces this. Also what does happens when you remove the `replace()`

Comment: @charlietfl if i remove the replace . Many divs(not two divs) get output but with undefined values for div thumbs and title and  id!

Comment: It's only valid if quotations are removed and some extra characters.
https://jsfiddle.net/y7gzft5r/

Comment: @Anuga do you think the way i remove those equations is not correct ?How to change structure of the json to make it valid if i don't use replace ? The api has lots of data staring and ending with those quotations!

Comment: problem is the `\r\n`   ...those shouldn't be visible and need to be removed. Source is really corrupted...where does it come from?

Comment: @charlietfl it is from external API i receive it via post method and need to use it in cordova android app. That is the away i recive it how i can remove those \r\n?

Comment: is there a proxy in the middle ...or is this a direct request to that api? As for how...would take more regex. Are you sure some format parameter isn't missing in the request?

Comment: I use cordova plugin to make post request to API url and i receive the response in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem by removing both quotations,\r\n and some other unnecessary things with following method:

```
data = data.replace("\"[", "["); 
data = data.replace("]\"", "]");


data = data.replace(/\\r\\n/g, ""); 
data = data.replace(/\\/g, "");

data = data.replace("n\"", ""); 
data = data.replace("\")", ""); 
data = data.replace("\",", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

While using a well formatted JSON input.
It worked: [Example on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y7gzft5r/3/)

```
[{
    "itemID": "1",
    "itemTitle": "First",
    "itemText": "first one",
    "ThumbUrl": "http:\/\/somesite.com\/1.jpg",
    "itemContent": null
 },{
    "itemID": "2",
    "itemTitle": "Second",
    "itemText": "second one",
    "ThumbUrl": "http:\/\/somesite\/2.jpg",
    "itemContent": null
}]
```

Quotations can stay, but the extra \r\n needs to be removed.

```
data = data.replace("\\r\\n", "");
```

Should be enough.

Comment: so you suggest that i put the json response as new variable ?How to format the json the way you did it when i receive the json data via ajax ?data = data.replace("\\r\\n", ""); didn't remove the \r\n in my case

Answer (score 0):

It works when the result from the AJAX call is parsed twice, I don't really know the reason behind it but to me, it looks like it removes all the unnecessary spaces and forms the JSON string properly at the first parse function call and then when the parse function is called again it converts it to a JavaScript object.

The js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("./data.html", function(data, status) {
        $("#area1").text(data);

        // parse JSON response
        var json = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data));

        console.log(json);

        // then loop the single items
        for (i in json) {
            // create HTML code
            var div = "<div class=\"image\">\n" +
                "<a href=\"javascript:dofunction('./test.php?title=" + json[i].itemTitle + "&TargetUrl=http://somesite.com/" + json[i].itemID + "')\">\n" +
                "<img src=\"" + json[i].ThumbUrl + "\" alt=\"..\" />\n" +
                "</a>\n" +
                "</div>\n";

            $("#myDiv").append(div);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the [plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/tRQAokhGVlGiv9RXWmQJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

The issue mostly with `parse()`, which expects `JSON(received as JSON)`,

please check with `JSON.stringify(data)`. You also need to remove the `\n , \r...`

`data = data.replace(/(?:\\[rn]|[\r\n]+)+/g, "")`

Answer (score -1):

Your JSON looks fine, the problem is caused by the replace method.
You can simply parse the data like this:

```
var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(data);
```

jsonResponse is a json array that you can do whatever you want with it.

Hope this help.